# scrapy https proxy 403 error - works in curl

Tags: python, http, https, proxy, scrapy

I have a scrapy 1.4.0 project on Linux with HttpProxyMiddleware enabled, i.e. my settings.py includes this:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 10,
}
```

when I run my spider (named sslproxies) using the following command, I get an error:

```
export https_proxy=https://123.123.123.123:3128
scrapy crawl sslproxies -o output/data.csv
```

The relevant error:

```
2017-08-15 18:57:20 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (403) <GET https://www.sslproxies.org/> (referer: None)
2017-08-15 18:57:20 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <403 https://www.sslproxies.org/>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2017-08-15 18:57:20 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

The 403 implies that the request is forbidden. However if I test the proxy server using curl:

```
curl -vx https://123.123.123.123:3128 https://httpbin.org/headers
```

I get a valid response and it uses the proxy server:

```
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to httpbin.org:443
> CONNECT httpbin.org:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: httpbin.org:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
```

If I bypass the proxy by unsetting the https_proxy environment variable the spider works.
Am I missing something in the scrapy http proxy middleware config?

Answer (score 0):

```
2017-08-15 18:57:20 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (403) <GET https://www.sslproxies.org/> (referer: None)
```

States your Spider is making request to `https://www.sslproxies.org/`

Do this, create another middleware like this

```
class CustomProxyMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request, spider):

        request.meta['proxy'] = "https://123.123.123.123:3128"
```

This will mean proxy is being used by each request your Spider makes.

Comment: Is this not what HttpProxyMiddleware is supposed to be doing?

Comment: I never tried to set an environment variable, so i dont know that should work or not, I recommend you to use my suggestion. And with that i will be able to help you more